# How to loop through array, increase count and output

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Im trying to loop through an array in PHP and use the counter to increment the page number. If I replace $counter with "1" - it works. I know something isnt right here.

```
  for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 10; $counter++) {

  $messages = $client->readMessages(array('pageNumber' => $counter,
                      'includeContent' => false,
                      'filter' => $filter))->return;
}



  var_dump($messages);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting *$messages* every iteration.

Make *$messages* to be an array and instead of:

```
$messages = ...
```

Append to an array by

```
$messages[] = ...
```